# how to bold and change font size of the tableview item or row in javafx?

Tags: javafx-2

In my project I'm using javafx and there is a `TableView` in which there are four columns i.e `source`, `target`, `score`, `date` and I want either a single word in the column or the whole row to be bold or italic and to change the font size.

```
public void readtextfile(String data) //data contains the location of the file
    {

        data1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        tab = new Tab("new" + (tabPaneTableview.getTabs().size() + 1));//create a new tab every time loaddatabase() is called
        tabPaneTableview.getTabs().add(tab);//tab is added in tabpane
        tabPaneTableview.getSelectionModel().select(tab);//the particular tab is selected
        tv_new = new TableView<>();
        tc_id = new TableColumn<File, Integer>("Id");
        tc_source = new TableColumn<File, String>("Source");
        tc_target = new TableColumn<File, String>("Target");
        tc_score = new TableColumn<File, String>("Score");
        // tcUsername=new TableColumn<File,String>("Creation User");
        //tcCurrentdate=new TableColumn<File,String>("Date/Time");
        tcNote = new TableColumn<File, String>("Note");
        tcStatus = new TableColumn<File, String>("Status");
        //tcConfirm=new TableColumn<File,String>("Confirm");
        //tcLock=new TableColumn<File,String>("Lock");
        //tcStatus.getColumns().addAll(tcConfirm,tcLock);
        //tcPostag=new TableColumn<ExcelFile,String>("Pos Tag");
        tv_new.getColumns().addAll(tc_id, tc_source, tc_target, tc_score, tcNote, tcStatus);
        tab.setContent(tv_new);
       tv_new.setPrefHeight(250);
        tv_new.setRowFactory(new Callback<TableView<File>, TableRow<File>>() {
            @Override
            public TableRow<File> call(TableView<File> param) {
                final TableRow<File> row = new TableRow<File>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(File row, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(row, empty);
                        if (!empty)
                            styleProperty().bind(Bindings.when(row.selectedProperty())
                                    .then("-fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-font-size: 16;")
                                    .otherwise(""));
                    }
                };

                return row;
            }
        });
    public boolean getSelected() {return selected.get();}
    public BooleanProperty selectedProperty(){return selected;}
```

I'm using this code but it doesn't yield the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the solution that you are looking for but this might help you.

```
.table-row-cell:hover {
  -fx-border-color: red; /* Vertical Lines*/
  -fx-control-inner-background: #c1c1c1;
  -fx-border-width: 1;
 }
```

This is a fragment of code that I have provided because I think that changing the text font, just selecting a row is a bit complicated because you have to keep in mind that the text is linked by the column or cell that is focused.

This piece of code has to be included in the css file and from sceneBuilder or from the code you have to include the stylesheet. Good luck.